# Check if TFS is express version

Tags: c#, visual-studio, tfs, alm

How can I check if my TFS is really a Express version?

Despite all the evidence, it still allows me to use more than 5 users consecutively.

**Image 1:**

[image]

**Image 2:**

[image]

**Image 3:**

[image]

**Image 4:**

**[image: Image 4:]**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Express edition is essentially the same TFS as you get when you install the TFS Basic wizard except that the install is trimmed down and streamlined to make it incredibly fast and easy.

So, the version number is the same as the full version. We can simply identify the Express version from the "**Programs and Features**" as shown in the **image3** you posted. You can check [What version of Team Foundation Server do I have?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tfssetup/2013/11/21/what-version-of-team-foundation-server-do-i-have/)

There are some limitations for the Express version, you can also identify it by these limits (See [Brian Harry's blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/bharry/2012/02/23/coming-soon-tfs-express/)):

> - Install limitations: no Sharepoint integration, no reporting.
> - Is limited to **no more than 5 named users**. (***See below clarification***)
> - Only supports SQL Server Express Edition (which we’ll install for
>     you, if you don’t have it)
> - Can only be installed on a single server (no multi-server
>     configurations)
> - Excludes the TFS Proxy and the new Preemptive analytics add-on.

Please also reference below article to distinguish the differences compare with the full version. It's still available for TFS 2017.
[Comparison of Team Foundation Server’s Editions](https://lajak.wordpress.com/2013/01/09/tfs-2012-versions-of-team-foundation-server/)

**Clarification for the user limits:** See [**license-terms**](https://www.visualstudio.com/license-terms/mt171584/) for details.

> The up to 5 named users limits is for Running Instances of the Server
>   Software.
>
> You may connect any combination of up to five (5) users or devices to
>   access the one instance of the server software in cases where a CAL is
>   required. But the 6th and more users is available if **A CAL is not
>   required**. eg:
>
> - To view, edit or enter work items;
> - For accessing Visual Studio Team Foundation Server through a pooled    connection from another integrated application or service;
> - For providing feedback via the Feedback Client for the software.

Comment: Epic answer. Thank you so much @Andy-MSFT.